# Using parentheses to group expressions in case

Tags: bash, shell, switch-statement, case, glob

I would like to group expressions with () in `case`, like so:

```sh
case a in
'*(a|b)*') printf '%s\n' 'something something';;
esac
```

This has not yielded any success though. I have also tried:

`*(a|b)*`
`*'('a|b')'*`
None of which I had success with.

Comment: Have you already decided that the standard `*a*|*b*)` isn't suitable in your case?

Comment: If `a` and `b` are actually single letters (not placeholders for longer strings/patterns), you can use the pattern `*[ab]*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be Bash specific:

You need to enable `extglob` and use this specific syntax

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

case "$1" in
*@(a|b)*) printf '%s\n' 'something something';;
esac
```

See `man bash`:

> If the **`extglob`** shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several extended pattern matching operators are  recognized. In the  following  description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated by a `|`.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the following sub-patterns:
>
> - `?(pattern-list)`
>   Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
> - `*(pattern-list)`
>   Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
> - `+(pattern-list)`
>   Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
> - **`@(pattern-list)`**
>   Matches one of the given patterns
> - `!(pattern-list)`
>   Matches anything except one of the given patterns

Alternatively you can have the `case` continue execution with the next pattern's commands group, using a special `;&` marker at end of the commands group.

This is **NOT POSIX** but handled by **`bash`**, **`ksh`** or **`zsh`** still:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

case "$1" in
  *a*) ;& # Continue to next commands group
  *b*) printf '%s\n' 'something something';;
esac
```

And now, as [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) pointed-out in a comment.

**THE POSIX WAY**:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

case "$1" in
  *a*|*b*) printf '%s\n' 'something something';;
esac
```

Answer (score 5):

You can convert to the basic pattern matching as shown below:

```
case 'a' in
*a*|*b*) printf '%s\n' 'something something';;
esac
```